# Removing links from header

Tags: magento2, header, link

```
<div class="page-wrapper"><header class="page-header"><div class="panel wrapper"><div class="panel header"><ul class="header links">        <li class="greet welcome" data-bind="scope: 'customer'">
        <span data-bind="text: customer().fullname ? $t('Welcome, %1!').replace('%1', customer().fullname) : ''"></span>
    </li>
    <script type="text/x-magento-init">
    {
        "*": {
            "Magento_Ui/js/core/app": {
                "components": {
                    "customer": {
                        "component": "Magento_Customer/js/view/customer"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    </script>
<li><a href="http://192.168.0.75/admin/" >Admin</a></li>
```

I would like to remove link to admin panel, but there is no li class so I can't remove it by using **default.xml** file

Comment: What link do you want to remove?